# Tab completion doesn't complete paths with escaped space

Tags: cygwin, bash-completion

For a while now I'm experiencing an annoying bash-completion problem, namely it doesn't work when a path contains an escaped space. For example, I am in /cygdrive/c and type

```
$ cd Pro
```

pressing Tab key completes to "cd Program", pressing twice shows all directories with this "Program" prefix:

```
Program Files/       Program Files (x86)/ ProgramData/
```

I want to cd to "Program Files" so I type

```
$ cd Program\
```

(with space after backslash) and from now on pressing Tab does nothing. It used to work some time ago but I cannot identify when exactly it stopped. Any hints on what can be the cause of this?

Comment: The only time I've encountered this is when the shell thinks your prompt is ambiguous. When I do this on my system it correctly picks "Program\ Files" and prompts me for the next part of the completion.

Comment: Yup, it seems to work _sometimes_. For example if I create a directory `test\ test` in my home dir, it completes. Then when I add another directory `test\ test2` it only completes to `test\ test`, but then it doesn't want to suggest the rest of the path. After deleting `test\ test`, completion for `test\ test2` starts to work again... Weird

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. It doesn't cycle through them, just pushes it out as far as it can before it needs your help.

Comment: But it should also suggest available paths after tapping tab 2 times (that's what it normally does). Ok extending on the example, imagine I have two directories `test\ test` and `\test\ test\ 2` (note additional space before 2). If I type `cd test\ test\ ` and press tab it should be already enough for it to resolve to `test\ test\ 2` but it doesn't in my case :(.

Comment: Works fine here. Sorry!

Comment: Does it help if you remove the `bash_completion` package or run `complete -r cd`? I was having your problem with `cd` but not other programs like `ls` and the those changes fixed the problem.

Comment: @BeingQuisitive Yup, I tried running `complete -r cd` and it fixed the issue. Removing the package wasn't necessary. If you write an answer I will accept it.Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the there is a problem with the `bash_completion` package. I was having your problem with `cd` but not other programs like `ls`. You can either remove that package or put `complete -r cd` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: FWIW, upgrading bash-completion from 1.3 to 1.3.1 fixed this for me.